# Showing that $RP^1$ is an orientable smooth manifold and $RP^2$ is not orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

1. Show that $RP^1$ is an orientable smooth manifold

From a set of lecture notes, this is how orientation is defined:
[image]

I want to note that this section is even before the section on tangent spaces, so I should be able to do this problem without too many advanced theorems.

Now if we take the standard charts on $RP^1$, we get that $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}(z_1)=\phi_2[1,z_1]=1/z_1$. And in this case, the jacobian matrix, which is just the derivative, is $\frac{-1}{z^2}$ which is clearly not positive anywhere, so using the standard charts does not work, but I think we can make a slight adjustment to the first chart. If we define $\phi_1[x_1,x_2]=\frac{-x_2}{x_1}$ (or we can do this for $\phi_2$ and get the same result), we get an extra negative sign does the derivative of the transition map would be $\frac{1}{z^2}$ giving us a positive value. Now I just want to ask whether I am actually allowed to make the adjustment to the charts.

2)$RP^2$ is not orientable
I am not sure how to do this one with only using the basics of manifolds. Of course, with differential forms, it should be easy to prove that  $RP^n$ is not orientable for all n even, but without any of that machinery, showing that no such orientable atlas exists seems like a difficult task.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111261/oriented-atlas-for-mathbbrp3/4111454#4111454).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that:

**Proposition:** *if $\pi: X \to M$ is a smooth regular covering then $M$ is orientable if and only if $X$ is orientable and automorphisms maintain the same orientation of $X$.*

In your case $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n=\mathbb{S}^{n}/<f>$ where $f : \mathbb{S}^{n} \to \mathbb{S}^{n}$ is the antipodal map, i.e. $f(x)=-x$. Furthermore define $\pi : \mathbb{S}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ the quotient map.
Now, if $n$ is even, $f$ change the orientation and then $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is not orientable. If $n$ is odd, $f$ maintain the orientation and then $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is orientable.