# Show that $\mathbb RP^n$ with the standard smooth structure is orientable if and only if $n$ is odd

Tags: differential-geometry, jacobian, orientation, non-orientable-surfaces

> Show that $\mathbb RP^n$ with the standard smooth structure is orientable if and only if $n$ is odd.

I tried to show that the Jacobian of the transition map
$$(u_1,u_2,\dots ,u_n)\mapsto \left(\frac{u_1}{u_i},\dots ,\underbrace{\frac{1}{u_i}}_{j-\text{th}},\dots ,\frac{u_n}{u_i}\right)$$
is positive only when $n$ is odd.

But, the sign of the Jacobian actually depends on whether $i$ is less than or greater than $j$.

Is there any other map that I can use?

**Edit**: I don't know why someone would close this question as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111261/oriented-atlas-for-mathbbrp3). My question is clearly much more general- the Jacobian of the general map is a much more complicated object, and the given link does not provide any insight on why it is an if and only if condition.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111261/oriented-atlas-for-mathbbrp3)

Comment: It is a quotient of $S^n$ by a group $\pm \operatorname{Id}$. Now if $n$ is even then $- \operatorname{Id}$ changes the orientation of $S^n$. That is the problem.  So you approach not from the algebraic geometric side but from diff geometry side.

Comment: The usual charts do not provide an oriented atlas, you need to multiply the original chart by $(-1)^i$. See my answer to the recently asked [Proving $\Bbb{RP}^n$ is orientable if and only if $n$ is odd.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4693677/568204) for more details using the atlas-definition rather than something else (though other techniques are far nicer IMO).